# How would you be able to check if there are at least 4 letters after a string in PHP

Tags: php, laravel

Currently I have it setup that if a user enters an invite, it will check if it starts with the right url. But how would you be able to check if there are at least 4 characters after the url?

url should like like this: `https://discord.gg/AB1C`...

My php (laravel) code that checks if the invite begins with the right string

```
$inviteok = substr($request->invite, 0, 19 ) === "https://discord.gg/";
$inviteok = substr($request->invite, 19, 24 ) == // validation?
```

Comment: Your title says 4 letters, your question than says about 2 letters, can you give an actual example of what is and isn't valid?

Comment: @NigelRen Hi, sorry about, edited the post with a better description of what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use strlen

```php
$urlok = substr($request->invite, 0, 19 ) === "https://discord.gg/";

if($urlok && strlen($request->invite) > 23) {
    // do your thing here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `Str::after` method returns everything after the given value in a string. The entire string will be returned if the value does not exist within the string:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$slice = Str::after('This is my name', 'This is');

// ' my name'
```

The `Str::length` method returns the length of the given string:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$length = Str::length('Laravel');

// 7
```

Then you can do something like

```
$lettersAfterUrl = Str::after($completeUrl, 'https://discord.gg');
$numLettersAferUrl = Str::length($lettersAfterUrl);
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

How about using `preg_match()` to parse entire URL in one call?

```php
$isValid = (bool) preg_match('#^https:\/\/discord\.gg\/[A-Z0-9]{4,}$#', $request->invite);
```

I'm assuming you are looking for A-Z and 0-9 characters only.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `parse_url()`, this splits up the URL into the parts and you can check them individually...

```
$invite = "https://discord.gg/AB1";
$parts = parse_url($invite);
$inviteok = $parts['host'] == 'discord.gg';
$inviteok = strlen($parts['path']) > 4;
```

note that `$parts['path']` will be something like `/AB1C`, so account for the length being > 4.